# extract number between tags

Tags: python, regex

I want to get the number `8` from the string `<div class="abc">+8</div>`.

Note that `abc` is not fixed. It is a string and may be `xyz` next time.

How to get the number?

Comment: [**Do not parse HTML with regex!**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454)

Comment: where is that string coming from?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to get the number `8` from the string `<div class="abc">+8</div>`.

You're not being specific enough.

```
'<div class="abc">+8</div>'[18]
```

gives you `'8'`. This works if `abc` is `xyz`, too.

Do you expect that the numbers are always prefixed with `+`? (I'm guessing `-` is an option, too). Are they always inside `<div>` tags? Are `<div>` tags used for anything other than keeping these numbers? Can the `<div>` that surrounds a number also contain other things than the number? Could any `<div>` contain user-defined text that looks like these numbers in the source code? Before you can define your problem more concretely, you will risk false positives.

```
[ int(x) for x in re.findall(r'<div[^>]+>([+-]\d+)</div>', s) ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here with beautiful soap :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(string)
tag=soup.div
print(tag.string)
```